# Pluggable Javascript (SPA) application development

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modular, single-page-application

I am currently evaluating technology stack for my next pluggable JavaScript(SPA) project. After researching couple of months, I end up with 2 frameworks.

1. [ScaleApp](http://scaleapp.org/)
2. [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org)

I really like the **ScaleApp** architecture and idea behind the framework as well as **AngularJS** features and popularity. Is there any way I can integrate best parts of both the frameworks to create a pluggable JavaScrit application?

Comment: If you're asking for software recommendations, then this question is off topic here. "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"; that's the close reason.  Haven't yet voted to close, so you have a chance to narrow your question down into something that is neither too broad nor a software rec.

Comment: Hey, I wants to know whether anyone tried this combination before?

Comment: Then remove the software recommendation request.

Comment: Recommendation request removed!

Comment: @TapasJena What did you end up using? If possible can you share some resources to build pluggable js application?